# Setting up navigation back button and navigation view stack?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to change navigation back button title as "Back" and trying to delete a range of **viewControllers** from the **navigationController**. My code block as below:

```
func SetUpNavigationBackButtonAndNavigationViewStack()
{
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController?.viewControllers as [UIViewController]
    if(self.navigationController?.viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2].nibName == "OrderApprovalVC"
    && OrderBag.bag.count == 0)
    {
         var newBackButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: nil, action: nil)
         self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = newBackButton

         let navigationArray: Array<UIViewController> = self.navigationController?.viewControllers as [UIViewController]
         for(var i=1; i<navigationArray.count-1; i++)
         {
             viewControllers.removeAtIndex(1)
         }
         self.navigationController?.viewControllers = viewControllers
         viewControllers.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    }
}
```

I ran this code and I saw that, it removes the needed **viewcontrollers** from the **stack view** and go back due to clicking back button. However, after go back operation, there shouldn't exist back button, but it exists. Moreover, If I click the back button, **removed viewcontrollers** still appear but not navigate them although deleting those viewcontrollers.
Also, my back button title did not change. How can I solve this problem ? What is the best solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting the viewControllers from the navigation stack you should better use the provided methods of `UINavigationController`:

```
func popToViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated animated: Bool) -> [AnyObject]?
```

or, to go all the way back to the rootViewController:

```
func popToRootViewControllerAnimated(_ animated: Bool) -> [AnyObject]?
```

This automatically deallocates and removes the viewControllers from the navigation stack.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to solve so much and I overlooked to use "popToRootViewControllerAnimated" thank you again @zisoft :)